# Placement of Product Quantity Input Field on WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, woocommerce

I've been working on this for well over two months and I realize that I need help. While I'm leaning a lot from reading and studying, I don't fully understand some of the stuff that others tell me.

As this is a project for school, I appreciate any help I can get and please -- whatever you suggest or tell me to do, please explain it so that I can follow along.

**Idea:**
A one-page-checkout for WooCommerce where the customer can change the quantity and remove products.

**Current design:**
Please see image.[View image in a new tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjIV4.png)

**Desired design:**
The quantity field should be moved "up" and next to the "remove" link.

I do not know how to accomplish this and neither do I do know if this code is optimal as an overall. If there are suggestions on how to make it better or cleaner or more optimal, please let me know.

**Here's the code in full:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'qty_change_remove_item_checkout_order_review', 1000, 3);
function qty_change_remove_item_checkout_order_review( $quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    $_product = $cart_item['data'];

    if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {

        $product_quantity = sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="" />', $cart_item_key);

    } else {

        $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(

            array(

                'input_name' => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",

                'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],

                'max_value' => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),

                'min_value' => '1',

                'class' => 'qtyinput',

                'placeholder' => 'Qty',

                'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),

            ),

            $_product,

            false

        );

    }

    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    foreach ( $cart as $cart_key => $cart_value ) {

        if ( $cart_key == $cart_item_key ) {

            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

            $_product = $cart_item['data'] ;

            if ( ! wp_is_mobile() ) {

                $remove_product = sprintf(

                    '<a href="%s" class="remove-product" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s">Remove</a>',

                    esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_key ) ),

                    __( 'Remove from this order', 'woocommerce' ),

                    esc_attr( $product_id ),

                    esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() ),

                    esc_attr( $cart_item_key )

                ); 
            } else {

                $remove_product = sprintf(

                    '<a href="%s" class="remove-product-mobile" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s">&#9746;</a>',

                    esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_key)),

                    __( 'Remove from this order', 'woocommerce' ),

                    esc_attr( $product_id ),

                    esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() ),

                    esc_attr( $cart_item_key )

                ); 
            }
        }
    }

    return '<br><span class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( 'Qty: %s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . ' / ' . $remove_product . '</span>'.$product_quantity.'';

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a <**br**> in the following line that's why it moved down.

```
return '<br><span class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( 'Qty: %s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . ' / ' . $remove_product . '</span>'.$product_quantity.'';
```

Comment: Oh my... How did I miss that? Thank you!
Did you find any code improvements?

Comment: Please validate if it works though, I can't really run this code as is. You can improve your code by asking yourself is it easy to, for example, edits, add new sections, expanding the `WC` class and etc. for future enhancement. I see you utilized a lot of Ajax code to improved user experience which is async and non UI-blocking. Don't quote me on this but as far as school project goes is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks :) I will look into what you said about the WC class and learn from it.

Comment: @LenaWeigler Sorry what I meant was edits, add new sections to the webpage, and  expanding the WC class. Good luck!